# Ubuntu crash when screen sharing

Tags: xorg, crash, wayland, 22.10

I have a problem with my laptop on which I run Ubuntu. Anytime I try to share a screen, either a window or the entire screen the os crashes after a while. It started on Ubuntu 22.04 and now I upgraded to 22.10 and I still have this problem. I tried with both wayland and xorg and the problem persists. What should I do next?

Thanks.

---

**Edit**: The problem happens on any program I share screen on like Discord or even web apps like Google Meet.
It does not fully reboot I think, I get a black screen then I get in the "users" window.

lspci | grep VGA : Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520].

And one more thing, I looked for this problem on the manjaro forums as well and I found a thread. [Here's a link](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/laptop-shuts-down-suddenly-when-screen-sharing-and-power-is-disconnected-or-connected/117114). It seems they solved it by downgrading the kernel version. So I tried it, I downgraded from 5.19.0-23 to 5.15.0-52 and although I still had one crash it works now for a longer time than before, I even had it open for like ~10 minutes without it crashing. Maybe it has something to do with that. Are there any known problems with those kernel versions related to this topic?

Comment: Please edit your question with the following information: What program do you use to share your screen? How exactly does your OS crash? Does it fully reboot or only relaunch your desktop environment/log you out? What GPU do you have?